# In MAUI, how to restore an app to be the visually on top of all other apps?

Tags: maui

If a MAUI app has been repositioned visually behind other apps, but an event occurs that requires it to be brought to the visual foreground for the immediate response of the user, what process steps are required across the platforms? Once responded to, how do you reposition it to where it was?

Answer (score 2):

For the Android and iOS, you can't make your app show on top of all other apps, because this should depend on the users. And you should use the **Toast**, **Alert** or **Notification** instead of the whole app show when your app is in the background.

And for the Windows, you can use the following code when you want to show your app on top of all other apps:

```
#if WINDOWS
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
(appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).IsAlwaysOnTop = true;
(appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).IsAlwaysOnTop = false;
#endif
```

Comment: If you use Siri or Google Voice, they can bring an app to the top, i.e., ask for driving directions and the GPS driving application appears and displays the route. The user doesn't have to touch anything; it's coded.

Comment: First of all, the Siri and Google Voice is system app which have the protected permission. And it's also operated by the user, only use speaking instead of the touching. In addition, if the developer can make his app show on the top casually, there will be many malicious softwares. @MarcGeorge

Comment: Adding a Popup to the application, when placed into the background, the Popup doesn't appear above the browser app I placed above it. To see it, I have to manually select the app from the app stack. Is there a property/parameter to enable that functionality?

Comment: No, the pop up can't work when the app is in the background. For the android and ios, the notification can show when the app is in the background and for the andorid, the toast also can do that. @MarcGeorge

Comment: I know it's possible for Android to have a background process pop up a dialog/window over all other apps (even the lock screen) because I have a third party app that does it. The question is whether you can do it with MAUI. Also, for example, Samsung's Reminder app does full screen pop-ups on top of other apps.